# How to Avoid Storing Web.Config Connection String Passwords in TFS

Tags: security, powershell, web.config-transform

For example, and this is just an example, could I place something like a tag in the web.config where the connection string or parts of it would be, and then have the username and password replaced during the build release process when the build goes out to a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to store the connection strings in IIS and they will be applied to the web.config automatically.

See this post
http://forum.winhost.com/threads/setup-the-connection-string-in-web-config.7592/